# Second time hiring manager not reaching back after telling me a specific date when she will contact me, should I follow up again?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

Its a small startup publishing company. The person who interviewed me was just the editor in chief of the magazine. That was on a Thursday two weeks ago. After the interview I thanked her and she replied that she will get back to me the next week. The next week went by no response, so I followed up and she replied two days after and said she needs more time and she'll get back to me on Wednesday.

That was yesterday, no response again. Its Thursday now and should I follow up again? How should I say it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a startup, and it seems to be a badly organised startup. Well, these things happen. First, don't cancel any other job interviews that you might have. Second, there are two possibilities: Either they don't want you, or they want you and can't get their act together. Ignore the first possibility since what you do doesn't matter.

I would call them again to get in. If you don't get the job because that upsets them, so be it. You wouldn't want to work with them anyway. On the other hand, you may easily not get the job by not calling. If they are a startup, they will want someone who gets things done. Including pushing in to get the job.

Comment: I don't have her number. We just talk through email. How should I compose my message?

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of things may happen that explain that lateness. If you are interested, you can try to phone or mail(better phone), to get more information. The most likely explanation is that they were so busy they didn't find the time to call you back. Though there are plenty of other possibilities.

As you did already call back once, don't push too much, it would be felt as harrassing. But you can ask. Most people have schedules far too full, and can't do everything they'd like to do.

Comment: Well, bad time management. You hire people so they do work, so you don't have to do the work yourself, so you have more time to do important things. If that editor doesn't have the time to call back a person they intend to hire, that's the worst possible time management.

Comment: All I can think of is that theyre a small company. like 10 people I think. And shes the editor in chief. Shes not an HR so shes doing lots of things that is not HR related. Also, its the holidays so im sure they have parties. I don't have her number. She just contacted me through linkedin. Should I message her now? Im just waiting for a go signal from you guys.

Comment: @gnasher729 like I said on my last comment, shes the editor in chief so im sure hiring people is not on her mind. Esp that the position is not for her team. its for a completely new team. The IT team to be exact which she has no idea about.

Comment: It's a startup. By not doing this work _now_ she is creating more work later. It doesn't reduce her workload. That's why it's bad time management. Best case, she'll be on the phone with the poster another five times which could have been avoided.